# Как вернуться на предыдущий фрагмент?

Tags: android

Есть `Activity` вызывающий `Fragment`ы поочередно - 3 штуки.
В `Activity` используется `MaterialDrawer` от Mike Penz. 
Во фрагментах по нажатию на кнопку `Back` в `Tollbar` происходит вызов `Drawer`'a, то есть вернутся на предыдущий фрагмент можно нажав только Физическую кнопку на самом телефоне. Есть ли какая либо возможность переопределить функционал кнопки которая появляется вызовом `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

UPD Сам код `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements KitchenFragment.CallbackOne {
    public static final String TAG = "myLogTag";

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Drawer drawer;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        fm = getFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        }

        drawer = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(mToolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.menu).withIdentifier(1),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.kitchen_title).withIdentifier(2),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.information_title).withEnabled(false)
                ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "position clicked: " + position);
                        Fragment fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
                        switch (position) {
                            case 1:
                                fragment = MenuFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                fragment = KitchenFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            default:
                                fragment = new Fragment();
                        }
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View view) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "CLICK");
                        if (!drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().isDrawerIndicatorEnabled()) {
                            onBackPressed();
                            return true;
                        } else
                            return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "CLCK!");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState = drawer.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen())
            drawer.closeDrawer();
        else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            drawer.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFirstSelected() {
        drawer.setSelection(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: возможно это сможет вам помочь:  http://androiddocs.ru/action-bar-dobavlyaem-knopku-home/

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из исходников библиотеки, которую указал автор ([MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)), нам нужно установить обработчик навигации использующийся библиотекой для установки `onNavigationClickListener` в `Toolbar`. Выглядит он так:

```
public interface OnDrawerNavigationListener {
    /**
     * @param clickedView
     * @return true if the event was consumed
     */
    boolean onNavigationClickListener(View clickedView);
}
```

Устанавливается он в момент построения Drawer из DrawerBuilder следующим образом:

```
    /**
     * handles the different logics for the Drawer Navigation Listeners / Indications (ActionBarDrawertoggle)
     */
    protected void handleDrawerNavigation(Activity activity, boolean recreateActionBarDrawerToggle) {
        //set the navigationOnClickListener
        final View.OnClickListener toolbarNavigationListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean handled = false;

                if (mOnDrawerNavigationListener != null && (mActionBarDrawerToggle != null && !mActionBarDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled())) {
                    handled = mOnDrawerNavigationListener.onNavigationClickListener(v);
                }
                if (!handled) {
                    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerGravity)) {
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerGravity);
                    } else {
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerGravity);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
...
```

Далее в этом же методе:

```
//if we got a toolbar set a toolbarNavigationListener
//we also have to do this after setting the ActionBarDrawerToggle as this will overwrite this
if (mToolbar != null) {
    this.mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(toolbarNavigationListener);
}
```

Находим возможность установить *mOnDrawerNavigationListener* в DrawerBuilder.java:

```
/**
 * Define a OnDrawerNavigationListener for this Drawer
 *
 * @param onDrawerNavigationListener
 * @return this
 */
public DrawerBuilder withOnDrawerNavigationListener(@NonNull Drawer.OnDrawerNavigationListener onDrawerNavigationListener) {
    this.mOnDrawerNavigationListener = onDrawerNavigationListener;
    return this;
}
```

Условие `(mActionBarDrawerToggle != null && !mActionBarDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled())` выполняеться по-умолчанию:

```
// enable the drawer toggle / if withActionBarDrawerToggle we will autoGenerate it
protected boolean mActionBarDrawerToggleEnabled = true;
```

В итоге инициализация будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Drawer result = new DrawerBuilder()
    .withActivity(this)
    .withToolbar(toolbar)
    .withOnDrawerNavigationListener(new OnDrawerNavigationListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationClickListener(View clickedView) {
                // реализация навигации (.popBackStack(), finish() и тд)
                return false;
            }
        })
    .addDrawerItems(
        //pass your items here
    )
    .build();
```

В случае если обработчик навигации возвращает false, обработку можно будет выполнить в стандартном методе:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed(); // или другое действие
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Так же автор библиотеки указал возможность менять иконку навигации ещё одним способом.

Показать иконку *"back arrow"* в качестве кнопки *Up*:

```
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

И что бы вернуть *"hamburger" (иконка бокового меню)* на место *Up*:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
result.getActionBarDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Не помогло, так как обработчик кликов не реагирует в случае использования этой библиотеки

Comment: @mamba0767 обновил ответ, пожалуйста дайте знать если это тоже не сработало

Comment: Так проблема остается, к сожалению, все той же, в документации я нашел как это можно организовать и как можно обработать нажатия - проблема остается - setNavigationOnClickListener ни в какую не хочет реагировать на нажатия

Comment: @mamba0767 Вы пробовали обработать нажатие на эту кнопку в onOptionsItemSelected методе вашего Activity?

Comment: Естественно. Метод отрабатывает в случае нажатия других элементов, но только не кнопки Back, которая открывает Drawer.

Comment: @mamba0767 Обновил ответ, пожалуйста дайте знать если проблема  всё ещё не решена

Comment: С данным приемом я так же встречался не раз - но он так же не отрабатывает, вот в чем проблема.